# How to initialise an array of objects in Eiffel?

Tags: eiffel

I am trying to implement a solution to the Producer-Consumer problem using Eiffel. I have an array `p` of class `PRODUCER` and an array `c` of class `CONSUMER` declared and initialized as following:

```
local
    p : attached ARRAY[PRODUCER]
    c : attached ARRAY[CONSUMER]
do
    !!p.make(1, 5)
    !!c.make(1, 5)
```

But when I try to access a feature in one of the components of the array (like `p.at(i).somefeature()`), it gives a runtime exception saying `Feature call on void target`.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is it because I am not calling a creation procedure for individual components of the array? Or is there a basic flaw in the approach to create the arrays? Thanks.

I figured the problem occurs because the individual components of the arrays (in this case, a producer or a consumer), being a reference type is initialized to void. The solution suggested is to use `make_filled(default_value:T;low,high:INTEGER;)`, where `T` is the complex type. An example is given for string arrays as

```
string_list : ARRAY[STRING]
string_list.make_filled(" ", low, high)
```

causing each element of `string_list` to be initialized to a string that is a blank space. Any help on how to give a default value for the class `PRODUCER`? Thanks

I think I figured out the solution to the problem. I just had to create an instance of `PRODUCER` and `CONSUMER` and use those in the default value in `make_filled`. Then I can manipulate `p[i]` and `c[i]`.

This is not a super efficient way, so if there is a better solution, please do share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`{ARRAY}.make_filled` is normally used when all the elements of the array should be the same. If the elements are different, the array can be filled one by one:

```
create p.make_empty
p.force (create {PRODUCER}.make ("producer 1"), 1) -- Use appropriate code to
p.force (create {PRODUCER}.make ("producer 2"), 2) -- create PRODUCER objects.
...
```

There is also a somewhat obsolete syntax to create arrays, so it has to be used with care:

```
p := <<
    create {PRODUCER}.make ("producer 1"), -- Or some other code
    create {PRODUCER}.make ("producer 2")  -- to create producers.
>>
```